# Ad Gallery Image Slider Issue with tab Container

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am Using Ajax Tab Container and having 3 Tabs in it in Asp.net C#. 1st Tab is used to Display an Image Gallery.

My Problem is if gallery Tab is active on pageload, then Add Gallery Plugin Working Fine if Galley Tab is inactive at pageload, ad gallery plugin is not working. Can anybody tell me what was the problem.

Comment: Do not initialize gallery on page load, initialize it when tab is active by tab event listener.

Comment: If i initialize gallery when tab is active it will post back whole page.

Comment: Check that required tab is active on page load then add initialization script using ClientScript or ScriptManager.